# Show information aggregated against a particular group in RDLC report

Tags: c#, wpf, ssrs-2008, reporting, rdlc

In my RDLC report I want to show my data grouped by a particular column. Here is the fields of the dataset that are returned by the method

Module name, Documentation date, Walk Date, Flushing date, Testing Date

I want to show in my report module wise how many items are Documented, Walked, Flushed, Tested. How I can do that?

I have tried to create Parent group on Module name but doing so repeats multiple lines per group ( as many lines as there are for that particular group), but I just want to show count of Documentation, Walk, FLushing etc) against each module.

Comment: Please include example of dataset with values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to count the number of non-NULL records for the **Date** fields in SSRS, you can use the ISNOTHING function to check each field:

```
=SUM(IIF(ISNOTHING(FIELDS!DocumentationDate.VALUE), 0, 1))
```

This just checks the field and counts the record as 1 if it's **not null**.